# how to convert table using pivot

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've got a set of data that looks something like this:-

```
product        May_Qty    June_Qty
---------      ---        -----------
   p1           2         44
   p2           1         54
   p3           5         55
```

**i want the result like**: (using pivot) or other methods

```
product        Month       Qty
---------      ---         -----------
       p1       May         2
       p1       June        44
       p2       May         1
       p2       June        54
       p3       May         5
       p3       June        55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit: The whole design smells a bit. Normally it is the other way round: Data is in a list and people want it as pivoted (wide) list for displaying purpose. So consider to work with a table with the design you want as target at the moment...

If you really want to stick with this, here are two approaches which produce the same output:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(product VARCHAR(100),May_Qty INT,June_Qty INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('p1',2,44)
,('p2',1,54)
,('p3',5,55);
```

With `UNION ALL` you create a derived table with the values as list and then you sort it

```
SELECT product,[Month],Qty
FROM
(
    SELECT product,5 AS MonthIndex,'May' AS [Month],May_Qty As Qty
    FROM @tbl 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product,6,'June',June_Qty
    FROM @tbl 
) AS parted
ORDER BY product,MonthIndex;
```

`UNPIVOT` does roughly the same:

```
SELECT up.*
FROM 
(SELECT product, May_Qty AS May, June_Qty AS June FROM @tbl) AS tbl
UNPIVOT
(Qty FOR [Month] IN(May,June)) AS up
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.this was very helpful for me

Comment: @NiteeshKumar I'm glad to read this! If this issue is solved I'd kindly ask you to tick the acceptance check below the vote counter. Once you've crossed the 15 points yourself, you are allowed to vote on contributions. This is the way to say *Thank you* here on StackOverflow. Thx